# Regarding Oracle Forms 12C and PJC beans

Tags: oracle, javabeans, oracle12c, oracleforms

We want to know about how to attach PJC bean in Oracle Forms 12C.
Let me know if anyone have answer.

Comment: Thats a process.... What did you do so far?

Comment: Maybe you can give a bit more information on what the problem is and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a PJC or Bean to a form is relatively easy.  Simply set the objects "Implementation Class".  More details about how to use PJCs and Beans can be found in the Builder Help.

You can also find many examples on the Internet.  Try this search:

https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+forms+java+pjc